# Select N points across a line using Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to select a random sample of points across a line, using `random` library but all I get are some weird lines.
The red line is generated from a list of 2-uples, by selecting the first index of each tuple, of each index of the list.

Here is the script sample:

```
path =[(403, 0), (403, 1), (403, 2), (403, 3), (403, 4), (403, 5), (403, 6), (403, 7), (403, 8), (403, 9), (403, 10)]

path_to_plot = [x[0] for x in path]#List only with the rows numbers

#Representation of the matrix
#plt.matshow(path_to_plot)
random_list = random.sample(path_to_plot,N_PLOT_SAMPLES)
random_list_y = random.sample(path_to_plot,N_PLOT_SAMPLES)
print("Random list:\n",random_list)
            
plt.plot(random_list, random_list_y)
plt.plot(path_to_plot,color='r',label="Path")#Plots the path
plt.show()
```

The generated plot is the following [image]

Is there a way to generate N points across that red line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that in the `plt.plot()` call, you are supplying `y` values from `random.sample()` as both `x` and `y` inputs. Here's a working example:

```
import random
import numpy as np

N_PLOT_SAMPLES = 10
# create some fake data
path_to_plot = np.sin(2*np.pi*np.arange(1000)/1000)
nsamples = len(path_to_plot)
# random indices
random_list_x = random.sample(range(nsamples), N_PLOT_SAMPLES)
# corresponding y values
random_list_y = path_to_plot[random_list_x]
# plot            
plt.plot(random_list_x, random_list_y, '*')
plt.plot(path_to_plot, color='r', label="Path")
plt.show()
```

Output:
[image]

(By the way, in the future it's good to include a minimal reproducible example of code. Currently people cannot directly run your code, because you don't supply `path`.)

Comment: I understood and it works great, but not in this example. I've edited the question with a sample of `path`. When I try to apply run it gives me a TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list.

Comment: Try to convert your data into a np.array first